# PHP + operator doesn't work all the time

Tags: php, arrays, operators

```
$var = compact('var1', 'var2') + (object)array(
  'var3' => 'asdf',
  'var4' => 'asdf'
);
```

doesn't work but why is that sometimes it works? like with

```
$var = array('var1' => 'asdf', 'var2' => 'asdf') + array('var3' => 'asdf', 'var4' => 'asdf');
```

Comment: What are you using the `+` operator for here? `+` is the mathematical addition operator, or the array union operator.... this doesn't look like mathematical addition to me, or a union of two arrays.... besides the fact that these aren't numeric values for addition, they aren't even the same datatype for array union

Comment: @MarkBaker I think `+` is also syntactic sugar for `array_merge()`. Question is why not to use the proper function

Comment: @kingkero - not a syntactic sugar, it's subtly different to an array merge

Comment: @MarkBaker I just realized that myself. [More info here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394157/whats-the-difference-between-array-merge-and-array-array) (for future readers)

Comment: Under what circumstances does it work/fail? Why are you casting the array to an object?

Comment: It will work as a union operator with two arrays, but not with an array and an object