# Difference between the orders of parameters in array_merge

Tags: php

Hey guys is there any difference between the order of parameters when you run `$arr1 = array_merge($arr1, $arr2);` versus `$arr1 = array_merge($arr2, $arr1)` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between array\_merge and array + array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394157/whats-the-difference-between-array-merge-and-array-array)

Comment: Duplicate of: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: it is not a duplicate. I was having a problem with those. One of them wasn't displaying the values in some keys, while the other one was displaying it. Those arrays had not a single key in common. Just after the merge some values in one array were missing (empty)

Comment: look carefully at $arr1 in left side of operation, and the parameters $arr1 and $arr2

Comment: I tested it locally it is working properly, I just don't know why I was having that strange behavior in my live site. It was very very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. According to Php function description: Merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the previous one. It returns the resulting array.

Comment: yea but i had completely different keys in those arrays, and one of them wasn't displaying the values of those keys

Comment: @ArditMeti Would you care to share your test data so we can replicate your problem? Otherwise there is no way to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

it is the order when merging array_merge ($ arr1, $ arr2); gives $ arr1 at the beginning and after $ arr2 whereas array_merge ($ arr2, $ arr1); gives $ arr2 at the beginning and after $ arr1

Comment: yea but i had completely different keys in those arrays, and one of them wasn't displaying the values of those keys while the reverse was displaying the values of those keys. I don't know if it's a bug or what... btw those values were same in many keys ex: ['key1'] => test, ['key2'] => test