# How to transfer one array to another array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a simple Two array

```
    $ages[] = array("Peter"=>22, "Clark"=>32, "John"=>28);

    $ages1[] = array("demo"=>22);
```

When I print this arrays it should be like following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Peter] => 22
            [Clark] => 32
            [John] => 28
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [demo] => 22
        )

)
```

But I want to create third array which will be show demo kye value into first array like following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Peter] => 22
            [Clark] => 32
            [John] => 28
            [demo] => 22
        )

)
```

Can we do two array into single array in PHP like Above

Comment: What have you tried?  Show us your attempts, we will help debug them as required.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394157/whats-the-difference-between-array-merge-and-array-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what are you trying to achieve here...little more context would be helpful. But this is how you can do this,

```
$ages[] = array("Peter"=>22, "Clark"=>32, "John"=>28);

$ages1[] = array("demo"=>22);

$result[] = array_merge($ages[0],$ages1[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do the job.

```
<?php    
$ages[] = array("Peter"=>22, "Clark"=>32, "John"=>28);
$ages1[] = array("demo"=>22);
$output = prepend_array($ages,$ages1);
print_r($output);

// Function to prepend arrays
function prepend_array()
{
    $num_args = count(func_get_args());
    $new_array = array();
    foreach (func_get_args() as $params){
        foreach($params as $out_key => $param)
        {
            foreach($param as $key => $value)
            $new_array[$out_key][$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $new_array;

}
```